# Flutter _CastError Null check operator problem

Tags: flutter

i have problem with validator. I used key: _formKey in widget but there is still an error.

"_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)"

[the CastError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ8gg.png)

```
class _CreateProfile3 extends State<CreateProfile3> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final heightController = TextEditingController();
  final weightController = TextEditingController();
  final ageController = TextEditingController();
```

```
TextFormField(
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'This field is required!';
                              }
                            },
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: weightController,
```

```
                                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('usersData')
                                      .doc(
                                          '${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}')
                                      .update({
                                    'height': heightController.text.trim(),
                                    'weight': weightController.text.trim(),
                                    'age': ageController.text.trim(),
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

Comment: The value of `value` of the `validator` can be `null`. So you should check first that it's not null before checking if it is empty.

`if (value != null && value!.isEmpty) {`

Comment: From the look of your code a few things may be the cause but first try that.

If the problem is still there, you should check the logs in your console. You should also check this video, it could help you learn to solve coding errors generally termed `bugs` :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3jw1JVNdPE

Comment: It is null even when i fill textformfields, so what should i do next?

Comment: Make sure you wrap the parent widget FormField with the Form widget and give it the formKey